# excel adding cell values together and putting in a new one

Tags: excel, vba

here is the code im trying:

```
Set found = Worksheets("Result").Range("A:A").Find(Prefix, , xlValues, xlWhole)
found.Offset(0, 1).Value = CInt(found.Offset(0, 1).Value) + CInt(C.Offset(0, 1).Value)
```

Prefix is a 3 digit number that is found in a column, what i then want to do is increase the cell to the right of where it is found by a cell one to the right of "C". I am getting a type mismatch error.

here is where c comes from:

```
For Each C In Worksheets("AMZ").Range("C2:C" & endRow).Cells
```

any ideas?

EDIT: Full code

```
Sub processData()

Dim endRow As Variant
endRow = Worksheets("AMZ").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For Each C In Worksheets("AMZ").Range("C2:C" & endRow).Cells
    Dim found As Range
    Prefix = C.Value
    C.Select

    'remove prefix
    If Not Left(Prefix, 3) = "FBA" Then
        'nothing
        If Mid(Prefix, 3, 1) = "-" Then
            Prefix = Left(Prefix, 2)
        ElseIf Mid(Prefix, 4, 1) = "-" Then
            Prefix = Left(Prefix, 3)
        Else
            Prefix = "-1"
        End If

        If Not Prefix = "-1" Then
            Set found = Worksheets("Result").Range("A:A").Find(Prefix, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            found.Offset(0, 1).Value = CInt(Val(found.Offset(0, 1).Value)) + CInt(Val(C.Offset(0, 1).Value))
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What values do you have in the in the found.offset(0,1) and the c.offset(0,1) ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If `found.Offset(0, 1).Value)` or `CInt(C.Offset(0, 1).Value)` are string values, like `""` or `"1234hello"` or anything that does not directly translate to an integer, you get the error you listed.

The easiest way to correct this, is to surround the value with the [Val(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx) function.
In your circumstance, you would use the following

`found.Offset(0, 1).Value = CInt(Val(found.Offset(0, 1).Value)) + CInt(Val(C.Offset(0, 1).Value))`

A note about Val, if the values you provide could not possibly be a number, it will default to 0. Otherwise it will take any numbers at the beginning of the string offered. For more about [Val read the link. (same as above)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx)

Comment: this is giving me a overflow error now.. I will post all my code in my question

Comment: Try using CLng instead of CInt. CInt fails if the value passed is >=32768.